# How to serve websites that perform complex computations?

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x

I am trying to create website on Django. This website will consider the user's historical transactions and serve the consolidation of those results. The consolidated results should not be pre-computed on the SQL database. Which programming modules should I use to achieve this?

Comment: you have to provide more information. Can you do your computations inside the database? If not, what kind of complex computations are we talking about?

Comment: The user will have their historical investment transactions by date. Then the web app will need to compute the dividends/share splits/withholding taxes/commissions. This will need to be based on the current and purchase date.

Comment: well if you cannot perform your operations on your database you should use some scientific library like Scypy which has fast C bindings for mathematical operations.